# Passport.authenticate and logout methods and flashes don't work until we route to a new page after the redirect

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I am having a weird problem with my authentication middleware. When I login, it redirects me to the home page as part of the `successRedirect` but doesn't log me in actually (as there was no change in the nav). However, when I hit another route from the home page ,it logs me in, displays the flash message, and as expected, the nav also changes. I experience exactly the same behaviour with logout. In the logout method, I added console logs after each line, and saw that all are logged at the same time, but it logs out only after a subsequent click.

**Edit**: this only happens if I redirect to the home page and not with other pages. After more checks, I see that the user isn't sent on the `req` of the home page (`/` route) and hence, the nav doesn't update. If I redirect them to another page(after either login or logout), it works perfectly fine and the nav updates as well. All pages are based on the same `layout.pug` and the nav is also defined in that.

app.js

```
const express = require(`express`);
const session = require(`express-session`);
const mongoose = require(`mongoose`);
const MongoStore = require(`connect-mongo`)(session);
const path = require(`path`);
const cookieParser = require(`cookie-parser`);
const bodyParser = require(`body-parser`);
const passport = require(`passport`);
const promisify = require(`es6-promisify`);
const flash = require(`connect-flash`);
const expressValidator = require(`express-validator`);
const routes = require(`./routes/index`);
const helpers = require(`./helpers`);
const errorHandlers = require(`./handlers/errorHandlers`);
const helmet = require(`helmet`);
require(`./handlers/passport`);
require(`./handlers/mail`);

// create our Express app
const app = express();
// view engine setup
app.set(`views`, path.join(__dirname, `views`)); // this is the folder where we keep our pug files
app.set(`view engine`, `pug`); // we use the engine pug, mustache or EJS work great too

// serves up static files from the public folder. Anything in public/ will just be served up as the file it is
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, `public`)));

// Use helmet

app.use(helmet());

// Takes the raw requests and turns them into usable properties on req.body
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Exposes a bunch of methods for validating data. Used heavily on userController.validateRegister
app.use(expressValidator());

// populates req.cookies with any cookies that came along with the request
app.use(cookieParser());

// Sessions allow us to store data on visitors from request to request
// This keeps users logged in and allows us to send flash messages
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    key: process.env.KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

// // Passport JS is what we use to handle our logins
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// // The flash middleware let's us use req.flash('error', 'Shit!'), which will then pass that message to the next page the user requests
app.use(flash());

// pass variables to our templates + all requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.h = helpers;
    res.locals.flashes = req.flash();
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    res.locals.currentPath = req.path;
    next();
});

// promisify some callback based APIs
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.login = promisify(req.login, req);
    next();
});

// After allllll that above middleware, we finally handle our own routes!
app.use(`/`, routes);

// If that above routes didnt work, we 404 them and forward to error handler
app.use(errorHandlers.notFound);

// One of our error handlers will see if these errors are just validation errors
app.use(errorHandlers.flashValidationErrors);

// Otherwise this was a really bad error we didn't expect! Shoot eh
if (app.get(`env`) === `development`) {
    /* Development Error Handler - Prints stack trace */
    app.use(errorHandlers.developmentErrors);
}

// production error handler
app.use(errorHandlers.productionErrors);

// done! we export it so we can start the site in start.js
module.exports = app;
```

routes/index.js

```
const express = require(`express`);
const router = express.Router();

const schoolController = require(`../controllers/schoolController`);
const authController = require(`../controllers/authController`);

const { catchErrors } = require(`../handlers/errorHandlers`);

router.get(`/`, (req, res) => {
    res.render(`index`);
});

router.get(`/events`, (req, res) => {
    res.render(`events`);
});

router.get(`/register`, authController.isNotLoggedIn, schoolController.registerForm);
router.post(`/register`, schoolController.validateRegister, catchErrors(schoolController.register));

router.get(`/login`, authController.isNotLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    res.render(`events`);
});

router.post(`/login`, authController.login);

router.get(`/logout`, catchErrors(authController.logout));

module.exports = router;
```

controllers/authController.js

```
const passport = require(`passport`);

exports.login = passport.authenticate(`local`, {
    failureRedirect: `/login`,
    failureFlash: `Failed Login!`,
    successRedirect: `/`,
    successFlash: `You are now logged in!`
});

exports.logout = async (req, res) => {
    await req.logout();
    console.log(`Logged out`);
    await req.flash(`success`, `Successfully logged out`);
    console.log(`Flashes sent`);
    await res.redirect(`/`);
    console.log(`Redirected`);
};

exports.isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next();
        return;
    }

    req.flash(`error`, `You must be logged in to do that !!`);
    res.redirect(`/login`);
};


exports.isNotLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        next();
        return;
    }

    req.flash(`error`, `You are already logged in !!`);
    res.redirect(`/login`);
};
```

handlers/passport.js

```
const passport = require(`passport`);
const mongoose = require(`mongoose`);
const SchoolUser = mongoose.model(`SchoolUser`);

passport.use(SchoolUser.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(SchoolUser.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(SchoolUser.deserializeUser());
```

What could have been the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably have an `index.html` file in your static folder, which `express.static` is exposing at `/`.

Ways to mitigate:

1. Remove / Rename `index.html` file.
2. Change the static route to some other path, like this:

   app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, `public`)));

now all your static content, will be available at '/public' instead of '/'.